# Lint]: Invalid argument at 2: cannot convert from bool to Function.prototype error on defining describe and It block on protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have created a protractor test using jasmine framework.

```
describe('title of the suite', () => {
    logger.info('Test Suite: tsc.signUp page');

    it('test description', async () => {
        logger.info('Executing: sample_test');

        await browser.get('https://angularjs.org/');

        const currentUrl = await browser.getCurrentUrl();

        logger.info('URL: ', currentUrl);

        expect(await browser.getTitle()).toEqual('AngularJS — Superheroic JavaScript MVW Framework');
    });
});
```

However, the editor is showing error as:
Lint]: Invalid argument at 2: cannot convert from bool to Function.prototype

Comment: Is there a line this is thrown against? Because I can't see why it would apply to anything here.

Comment: each and every line is showing red and on hovering mouse, mentioned error is shown.

Comment: update the question with complete spec file and the complete error.